# Is it possible to get local time with Google API?

Tags: google-api

I'm working on an app that it using Google API for maps, but the problem I am having is obtaining correct local time. I can not use JS, because a user can travel to a different location and probably won't change the time settings. Also the server seems to be somewhat off and I have no control over its UNIX time. However, anytime you google for local time, you get based on your location. Since my app is using location as well, shouldn't I be able to access that time as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done using [**Google Timezone API**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro):

1- First use Google Timezone API to obtain the user's time zone info, the api accepts the target time (**timestamp**) in UTC (as UNIX time in secs) and location data

2- The response contains three important fields:

- **dstOffset**: This is offset for day-light saving (secs)
- **rawOffset**: This is raw offset for given location without day-light saving (secs)
- **timeZoneId**: This is IANA time zone id

Using the first two you can get your date in JS as:

```
var localDate = new Date((timestamp + dstOffset + rawOffset) * 1000);
```

or by third one using [timezone-js](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js) or [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/).

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript) for using timezone.

Comment: Why multiply by 1,000?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. This is because the Date constructor accepts UNIX epoch in milliseconds and the returned data is in seconds. 1 sec = 1000 msec